# React + Splide.js Grid Extension functionality

Tags: javascript, reactjs, splidejs

So I can't find anywhere an example for Splide Grid Extension integration in React. How exactly does this work? What am I missing?

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

import { Splide, SplideSlide } from '@splidejs/react-splide';
import { Grid } from "@splidejs/splide-extension-grid";

import Container from "../layout/Container";
import Section from "../layout/Section";

import classes from './Jobs.module.css';

const Jobs = ({blok}) => {
    const [jobs, setJobs] = useState([]);

    ...

    return <Section>
        <Container>           
            
            <div className={classes.slider_wrapper}>
                <Splide aria-label="jobs slider" options={ {
                    pagination: false,
                    arrows: false,
                    grid: {
                        rows: 2,
                        cols: 2,
                    },
                } } extensions={{ Grid }}>
                        
                        {jobs && jobs.map(item => (  
                            <SplideSlide key={item.uuid} >                  
                                <div className={classes.item}>
                                    <div className={classes.content}>
                                        <div className={classes.title}>{item.content.title}<span>.</span></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>  
                            </SplideSlide>              
                        ))}
                    
                </Splide>
                
            </div>           
            
        </Container>
    </Section>
}

export default Jobs;
```

This only returns a normal Splide slider without a grid. How exactly can i get a grid of 2x2 for example?

Comment: I can only guess this is broken for splide newer version. Found this working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/solitary-pine-fvkkx?file=/src/App.js:55-120 using older dependencies. Time to find another slider I guess. Good job me :)

Answer (score 0):

For me when I use extensions grid, it works as desired. Here is the code.

```
<Splide
    tag="section"
    extensions={{ Grid }}
    options={{
      type: "loop",
      perPage: 1,
      perMove: 1,
      grid: {
        rows: 2,
        cols: 2,
        gap: {
          row: "1rem",
          col: "1rem"
        }
      }
    }}
  >
    {[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6].map((item) => (
      <SplideSlide>
        <div className="slide">{item}</div>
      </SplideSlide>
    ))}
  </Splide>
```

You can find Working Code Sandbox example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-lake-x8mvzf?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Hey, please provide your code solution (also) in your answer so it's not dependend on the availability of codesandbox. Additionally please avoid only-code answers and provide some more explanations.